# How to fetch json data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my json array.I want to get the data from gallery data in flutter

```
  {
        "status": true,
        "message": "Data Gallery",
        "data": {
            "gallery": [
                {
                    "gal_id": "21103",
                    "shop_id": "49",
                    "img": "1589530294IMG_8982.PNG",
                    "place": "6091",
                    "status": "New",
                    "title": "1",
                    "description": ""
                },
                {
                    "gal_id": "21102",
                    "shop_id": "49",
                    "img": "1589530294IMG_8981.PNG",
                    "place": "6091",
                    "status": "New",
                    "title": "1",
                    "description": ""
                }

            ]
        },
        "total": 2
    }
```

This function is use to call the http request

```
  List<Gallery> list;

  Future<List<Gallery>> getData() async {

    String link =Constant.base_url+"manage/api/gallery/all/?X-Api-Key="+Constant.API_KEY+"&start=0&limit=10&field=shop_id&ield=shop_id&filter="+Constant.Shop_id+"&parent=0&loc_id= ";

    final response = await http.get(link);
//    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var cat = categoryFromMap(response.body.toString());

    return list;
  };
```

How to access the gallery data?

My model class is

```
import 'dart:convert';

Category categoryFromMap(String str) => Category.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String categoryToMap(Category data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class Category {
  Category({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
    this.total,
  });

  bool status;
  String message;
  Data data;
  int total;

  factory Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
    status: json["status"],
    message: json["message"],
    data: Data.fromMap(json["data"]),
    total: json["total"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "status": status,
    "message": message,
    "data": data.toMap(),
    "total": total,
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.gallery,
  });

  List<Gallery> gallery;

  factory Data.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    gallery: List<Gallery>.from(json["gallery"].map((x) => Gallery.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "gallery": List<dynamic>.from(gallery.map((x) => x.toMap())),
  };
}

class Gallery {
      Gallery({
        this.galId,
        this.shopId,
        this.img,
        this.place,
        this.status,
        this.title,
        this.description,
      });

      String galId;
      String shopId;
      String img;
      String place;
      String status;
      String title;
      String description;

      factory Gallery.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Gallery(
        galId: json["gal_id"],
        shopId: json["shop_id"],
        img: json["img"],
        place: json["place"],
        status: json["status"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
      );


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "gal_id": galId,
    "shop_id": shopId,
    "img": img,
    "place": place,
    "status": status,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
  };
}
```

Please help me to retrieve the data.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to format your question a bit, but it looks like some lines are truncated and the code is incomplete. Please [edit] your question and make sure it's a [mcve]. That will allow people to try it, fix any problems, and post an answer. Can you also explain what's wrong with your code? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: hey i forget the Gallery modal class in flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `FutureBuilder` and check `connectionState` then display with   `Text(snapshot.data.data.gallery[index].img,)`

code snippet

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getData();
    ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Category> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.data.gallery.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Category categoryFromMap(String str) => Category.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String categoryToMap(Category data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class Category {
  Category({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
    this.total,
  });

  bool status;
  String message;
  Data data;
  int total;

  factory Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: Data.fromMap(json["data"]),
        total: json["total"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": data.toMap(),
        "total": total,
      };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.gallery,
  });

  List<Gallery> gallery;

  factory Data.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        gallery:
            List<Gallery>.from(json["gallery"].map((x) => Gallery.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "gallery": List<dynamic>.from(gallery.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class Gallery {
  Gallery({
    this.galId,
    this.shopId,
    this.img,
    this.place,
    this.status,
    this.title,
    this.description,
  });

  String galId;
  String shopId;
  String img;
  String place;
  String status;
  String title;
  String description;

  factory Gallery.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Gallery(
        galId: json["gal_id"],
        shopId: json["shop_id"],
        img: json["img"],
        place: json["place"],
        status: json["status"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "gal_id": galId,
        "shop_id": shopId,
        "img": img,
        "place": place,
        "status": status,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Future<Category> _future;

  Future<Category> getData() async {
    String jsonString = '''
   {
        "status": true,
        "message": "Data Gallery",
        "data": {
            "gallery": [
                {
                    "gal_id": "21103",
                    "shop_id": "49",
                    "img": "1589530294IMG_8982.PNG",
                    "place": "6091",
                    "status": "New",
                    "title": "1",
                    "description": ""
                },
                {
                    "gal_id": "21102",
                    "shop_id": "49",
                    "img": "1589530294IMG_8981.PNG",
                    "place": "6091",
                    "status": "New",
                    "title": "1",
                    "description": ""
                }

            ]
        },
        "total": 2
    }
    ''';

    var response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return categoryFromMap(response.body);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Category> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.data.gallery.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot
                                        .data.data.gallery[index].galId),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data.data.gallery[index].img,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```